# Questa dont detect warning concerning always_comb

Tags: system-verilog

I have a simple module:

```
module always_comb_error_ex
(
    input logic a, b,
    output logic y, z
);

// Error (10166): SystemVerilog RTL Coding error at always_comb_error_ex.sv(13): always_comb 
// construct does not infer purely combinational logic
// Info (10041): Inferred latch for "z" at always_comb_error_ex.sv(17)
// Info (10041): Inferred latch for "y" at always_comb_error_ex.sv(17)
always_comb begin 
    if (a > b) begin 
        y = 1;
        z = 0;
    end
    else if (a < b) begin
        // y = 0;  // missing output will create latch
        z = 1;
    end
    // else begin   // missing 'else' block will create latch
        // y = 1;
        // z = 1;
    // end
end 

endmodule
```

Since I'm using always_comb I should have some warning about latches.. but there is no warning by using Questa 10.7b

The tcl sctipt for compilation:

```
set work work
vlib -type directory $work
vlog -work $work +acc -sv -vopt -O5 +incdir+./ ../src/sv_test.sv
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all errors can be caught by simple parsing of the code, which is what `vlog` does. Some errors/warning will not show up until elaboration, which is `vsim`

Comment: I have a very simple tcl for simulation ```vsim -t 1ns -voptargs="+acc" test_tb
add wave -r test_tb/DUT/*``` how it can be changed to observe warning in console?